# I built a SQL version of JSFiddle - is it appropriate to update the SQL tag wiki?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I see that for the JavaScript tag, there is a suggestion that questioners use JSFiddle or JSBin as tools for formulating their question.  I also see that currently, there is no equivalent suggestion for the SQL tag (presumably because there haven't been many equivalent options).  I just built a site,  http://sqlfiddle.com, that I am hoping SQL questioners and answerers will find useful in the same way that http://jsfiddle.net is for JavaScript folks.  I've never updated the wiki for a tag before, and so I am not really familiar with the specific rules / expectations in that regard.  Also, since this is my site, I could see how my adding that to the wiki would seem like shameless self-promotion.  Is this something I should do?  Or should I just use my site to answer SQL questions for a while, and then see how it goes?

Comment: We do have [data.SE], which I've used a couple of times an "SQLFiddle" type of resource =)  +1 though, very cool idea.

Comment: @jadarnel27 I knew about the data explorer, but that is limited in a couple ways - 1) Can't provide your own schema/data & 2) You can't switch database backends.  So I'm hoping this will provide some more value in offering those options.

Comment: You willing to guarantee that your site won't ever go down? (I also have the same problem with the js sites)

Comment: @Won't I plan on following Bill's advice and only using my site as a reference, while posting the actual answer text directly in the answer on SO.  So, that's a round-about way of saying "no, I don't guarantee it won't ever go down", but if it does I am aiming to mitigate that somewhat based on usage.

Comment: Over 12,500 upvoted or accepted answers used SQLFiddle in the last year according to [this Data Explorer query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/158360/percentage-of-good-sql-answers-in-last-12-months-that-used-sqlfiddle), so I guess it did catch on with the community.  :)

Comment: Also, you might be interested in the discussion taking place at [Does Stack Exchange donate to SQL Fiddle?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215243/1288)

Comment: Hi @JakeFeasel. Have a look at [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321437/is-it-ok-to-promote-non-working-sql-fiddle/321442#321442) post. Basically, the problem is with SQLFiddle and it is getting worse and worse for the last few months. Sometimes the Fiddle is not working. Is there a way to make it more reliable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd hold off and see how it goes.  The community really needs to adopt a third-party resource like JSFiddle before it's appropriate to add it to a tag wiki.

When you add it to your own answers make sure you provide complete code in your answer and add the external link as a reference only.  Also, make sure you disclose your affiliation with the site when you use it in your own answers.

Comment: Sounds good to me.  Will do.

Comment: @JakeFeasel Good luck!  I hope it catches on.

Comment: Bill - it's been a few months now since I first asked about this, and I've seen quite a few different people using the site as a tool for SQL questions now.  Also, I've polished the site up quite a bit since I first asked.  I know there is no hard-and-fast answer here, but when would you say the "community" has adopted such a resource?  BTW - I'm happy to report that I've managed to get a fair bit of exposure over the last couple months, and feedback has been very positive so far.

Comment: @JakeFeasel Nice job on the updates.  A quick scan through the [search results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=relevance&q=url%3a%22http%3a%2f%2fsqlfiddle.com%2f*%22) shows that well over a dozen different people are using SQLFiddle to show demos in addition to their code, so I think it's okay to add it to the wiki.

Comment: Great, I've now submitted an update.

Comment: I tried to post an update to the wiki, but I guess my suggested edit was rejected.  Oh well.

Comment: @JakeFeasel I went ahead and added it for you. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info

Answer (score 1):

There is an option I've used quite a bit for SQL answers, but unfortunately questioners have not: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new