# Where to put a commity-owned tutorial for certain classes of users for specific types of questions

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I answer my own questions, even those where I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)

I'd like to have a community-owned venue where I/we could post material that would repeatedly be helpful to specific audiences; a FAQ/How-to-use-SO directed at small subsets of the community. But about using SO. If SO/SE has such a venue, I don't know it.  (If this does fall within the realm of what it's okay to use community wiki for, then my question is answered (once someone tells me)).

Specifically, I can see saying to lots of people posting SQL questions:

> "When you have a question about SQL, you can often get better and faster answers if you create a
>   SQLfiddle for the question.  That makes it 'cheaper' for someone to
>   put the time into making a concrete suggestion for you.  SQL fiddle
>   lets you...[etc].  Many people who read this aren't familiar with the
>   syntax of creating and populating tables; following are some
>   examples...'  Additionally, you should tag and title your questions
>   with these guidelines..."

Technically, it could go on any wiki software and not need Stack% blessing but is there already an appropriate way to do this without straying out of SE branded sites?

Comment: You may find the [AutoReviewComments script](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) useful if you wish to post these often. I find the variety among different users is for the best -- single-source statements often feel _very_ impersonal and "committee-driven".

Comment: Just ask and answer a canonical question. See here for details: [Can I answer my own questions, even those where I knew the answer before asking?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)

Comment: You may find this link useful, particularly since you mention SQL Fiddle: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120507/i-built-a-sql-version-of-jsfiddle-is-it-appropriate-to-update-the-sql-tag-wiki (btw - SQL Fiddle is my site - thanks for thinking it's worthy of such adoption!)

Comment: @JakeFeasel with sql fiddle, you're the single most signficant pioneer in human communication since Guttenberg or Berners-Lee anyway, I'll stop there 'cause if I said what I really think it would seem hyperbolic.  (But if I ever get famous you can stick that on your resume) Also, you answered my question: the "info" part of tags is essentially what I'm asking for in my question: it gets SO community scrutiny & maintenance.  For things that really could benefit by a tutorial, as Cody Gray says I can (one can) pose and answer a question.  BUT: [continues]

Comment: BUT... when I look at [the wiki for the sql tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info), there is nothing about Fiddle.  It seems to me like the link you give is consensus enough to add something; are you holding off thinking it seems self-promoting still?  Or am I missing the point, or not seeing what you're directing my attention to.

Comment: @LevinMagruder wow, thanks.  As you can see from that other thread, Bill approved updating the tag wiki, but that was only just today (original thread started months ago).  I'll be updating the wiki shortly.